# Extending Multiple models in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How do you set up CI2 to allow extending of multiple models?

I can only get it to extend one model (put in /application/core) named **MY_Model** (case sensitive).

To choose what model to extend I am doing;
in the model..

```
require_once APPPATH.'core/MY_Another_model.php';
class Test_model extends MY_Another_model {
...
}
```

I can't find where in the core system code where it states only to allow models that are being extended to be called MY_Model.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As I said in this question about the controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627587/code-igniter-2-how-to-extend-ci-controller-multiple-times/7627642#7627642) you just put both classes in the same MY_Model file. This file is used as part of the autoload feature of codeigniter, meaning that it will look for any files with the MY_ (or config defined) prefix.

You don't even need to call the class inside MY_Model you can potentially call it MY_Special_Model and have MY_Another_Model directly underneath

Comment: This is exactly what I do! It's not pretty because I like having each class in a separate file ... but it's the only way I could achieve this in CI.

Comment: @MikeMurko There is way to have separate classes in separate files, but it involve making a custom loader class and isn't worth the time and effort.

Comment: I have following class in MY_Model.php:

class Public_Model extends CI_Model
{

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

But it show me following error:
"MY_Model.php exists, but doesn't declare class MY_Model"

What should I do?
By the way, I am on CodeIgniter 3.1

Answer (score 8):

I've tried Cubed Eye's way, and it works, but here's another option:

Try adding a model to your autoload.php file. It could inherit from MY_Model (which inherits from CI_Model), and any additional models you load could inherit from it:

```
class Extended_model extends MY_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Another_model');
    }
}
```

(models/Extended_model.php)

```
class Another_model extends Extended_model {
}
```

(models/Another_model.php)

**EDIT:** I just realized that you're putting your extended model in the "core" folder.  This is only necessary for classes that extend the core CI_* classes (i.e. MY_Controller, MY_Model, MY_Input, etc.).  If you have a model extends MY_Model, put it in your models/ folder instead, and don't prefix it with "MY_".

Comment: Even though I have accepted the above answer, I have voted this up as I like having separate files per model, instead of stuffing them all in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you may try this hack, using `load_class` function:

This is your model extension:
application/core/Special_model_class.php:

```
class CI_Special_model_class extends CI_Model {...}
```

The name of the php file is without the CI_ prefix, although the class itself is with prefix!

The model based on this class within the models/ folder:
application/models/one_model.php:

```
class One_model extends CI_Special_model_class {...}
```

In order to make this work, you should call the `load_class` function from the controller:
application/controllers/one_ctrl.php

```
....
load_class('Special_model_class', 'core');
$this->load->model('Special_model_class');
....
```

Eventually, you may try to call `load_class` within the model, right before defining it.
application/models/one_model.php:

```
load_class('Special_model_class', 'core');
class One_model extends CI_Special_model_class {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the parent model class:**

```
class MY_Common_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
        function drop_table($table_name) {
        $this->connect();
         $this->dbforge->drop_table($table_name);

    }

}
```

**Here is the child model class:**

```
class MY_Model extends MY_Common_Model {
     function inset_table($table_name) {
        $this->connect();
        $this->insert_table($table_name);

    }
}
```

**in model:**

```
 $this->drop_table($edge_table);
```