# Codeigniter autoload controller not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have various controller is `core/` folder named `core/my_controller.php` and other controllers in `libraries/` folder as `libraries/user_controller.php`,`libraries/frontend_controller.php`. Now I am using this code below in `config.php` to autoload these files. But I dont think its working.

I am seeing this error message `Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in /home/manumakeadmin/manumake.com/2d/application/libraries/frontend_controller.php on line 3`

```
function __autoload($classname) {

    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I can make it work by manually including the files as

```
<?php
include_once APPPATH.'core/my_controller.php';

class Frontend_controller extends MY_Controller
{
```

But I was wondering if I could make the autoload code to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Library file names and class names must match and be capitalised](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) -  `Frontend_controller.php`

When [extending a core class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html), the file name must also match the class name. Capitalise the prefix and the first letter of the class name in the file: `MY_Controller.php` The prefix can be set in: `application/config/config.php`

Also ensure that your files are in the `application` directory, rather than `system`. This seems to be the case, but it's worth checking.

It's always a good idea to check the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) for naming conventions. For example, [model](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy) class names must have the first letter capitalised and the rest lowercase; the file name should be all lower case and match the class name.

---

However, it's very important to realise that [libraries in CodeIgniter aren't intended for extending core classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html), for example `CI_Controller`, which I assume `MY_Controller` is extending. Libraries should be used to:

> - create entirely new libraries.
> - extend native libraries.
> - replace native libraries.

I think it's likely that your `Frontend_controller` would be better located in: `application/controllers/`

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
But Once I was doing the same thing in my linux server, and I got error messages because I was using the filenames in capital letter to match them with model name

Comment: No worries! You're correct - [model file names should be all lower case](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy). It's always a good idea to check the naming conventions in the user guide.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [autoloading non-ci](http://blog.daanraman.com/coding/extending-a-controller-using-my_controller-in-codeigniter-2-0-and-above/) [classes technique](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) documented in those two links and [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636252/462002) before.

Adding an snippet to config.php to load those classes does the trick.

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_')
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

and adding your base class in `application/core/Base_Controller.php`